# How to delete more than one row in a matrix, not just last row, when using a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, matrix, delete-row

I tried to go about this myself and looked up online how to do this, but no direct answer. Basically, I am trying to delete the rows in a matrix that have more than 3 characters. My code is only deleting the last row. Rows 16-31 should be deleted. The `i` gets iterated, but only deletes the last column which satisfies the condition. However, more rows must be deleted. Thanks for the help in advance!

```
setwd("~/Desktop/Rpractice")

c <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

combine <- function (x, y) {combn (y, x, paste, collapse = ",")}

combination_mat <- as.matrix(unlist(lapply (1:length (c), combine, c)))

for (i in length(combination_mat)) {

  if (nchar(combination_mat[i]) > 3) {

  newmat <- print(as.matrix(combination_mat[-i,]))

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really do not need a loop to remove those rows, eg you can look for the rows with more than 3 characters and remove those (please note the `drop=FALSE` argument to keep the tabular format of the data instead of simplifying that to a vector):

```
> combination_mat[nchar(combination_mat[, 1]) <= 3, , drop = FALSE]
      [,1] 
 [1,] "1"  
 [2,] "2"  
 [3,] "3"  
 [4,] "4"  
 [5,] "5"  
 [6,] "1,2"
 [7,] "1,3"
 [8,] "1,4"
 [9,] "1,5"
[10,] "2,3"
[11,] "2,4"
[12,] "2,5"
[13,] "3,4"
[14,] "3,5"
[15,] "4,5"
```